# How to protect pdf report with password using thymeleaf as template engine and flying-saucer as rendrer

Tags: java, spring, flying-saucer

PDF is generating successfully but I want to protect it with a password.
flying-saucer-pdf doc does not help me.
I am using this example
[Using thymeleaf+flying-saucer-pdf+Spring Boot](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-To-Create-PDF-through-HTML-Template-In-Spring-Boot)

Comment: First of all thanks for referencing PDF creation from my blog. To set password in PDF you will need to use `PDFEncryption` class of flying saucer

Comment: Protecting a pdf using password has nothing to do with spring or thymeleaf. Removing those tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To set password in PDF with `Flying Saucer` PDF Creator use `PDFEncryption` class. To set password to your PDF, First create an instance of `PDFEncryption` and then use its method `setUserPassword()` like this:

```
final File outputFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf");
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
PDFEncryption pdfEncryption  = new PDFEncryption();
String password= "password@123";
pdfEncryption.setUserPassword(password.getBytes());
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setPDFEncryption(pdfEncryption);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os, false);
renderer.finishPDF();
```