# How to render password-protected PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, password-protection, flying-saucer

I am using Flying Saucer to generate PDF from XHTML. Rendering works nice, but any attempt to password-protect the PDF document fails with an Exception.

I am using code recommended by Ajit Soman in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46024498/4517737. A copy of code is shown below. 
If you un-comment the commented line, Exception is thrown in line "*renderer.createPDF(os, false)*".

The Exception is
"*Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException*"
(for JavaFX application).

For plain Java, the Exception is "*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.(PdfEncryption.java:147).....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable*"

```
final File outputFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf");
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
PDFEncryption pdfEncryption  = new PDFEncryption();
String password= "password@123";
pdfEncryption.setUserPassword(password.getBytes());
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

// the following line causes Exception
// renderer.setPDFEncryption(pdfEncryption);

renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os, false);
renderer.finishPDF();
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Thank you for your idea; I added this info into my question. I also have a full stack trace (97 lines) but I don´t know how to clip it here.

Answer (score 0):

For other users with a similar problem. I solved it by adding this to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
  <version>1.77</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcutil-jdk18on</artifactId>
  <version>1.77</version>
</dependency>
```

I worked on 9.6.1 version of flying-saucer-pdf and java 17